# unable to authenticate quay regsitry with remote docker login in terminal

Tags: docker, ssl, redhat, centos8, quay.io

I installed red hat quay in a centos based vm. I installed certs (openssl/letsencrypt) also for quay subdomain. quay and other dependencies are running in a docker container inside the VM.

After setting up QUAY and getting certs in quay configuration I am able to login into the subdomain using ssl with https://quay.example.com but when i try to login to container registry from terminal to pull and push containers I get error eg:

```
MBP:~ deepak.sandhu$ docker login https://quay.example.com
Username: deepak.sandhu 
Password: 
Error response from daemon: Get "https:*/v2/": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

what do we need to do for docker also to work with ssl. I have tried same with both openssl and lets-encrypt. Both time docker login from remote terminal fails, but ssl is working if i go to web-console.